# Bug using mobile site with moderator tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, mobile-web

This is a bug with the mobile site (as viewed on a browser, not through the app) using the moderator tools. Was able to reproduce on iOS 9.3.2 (Safari), but not on Android with either Firefox or Chrome.

When you go to a post with a flag and a review history, if you click the `mod` menu at the bottom of the screen followed by `show flag history` you get taken to the (non-mobile styled) flag history page.

On Safari only, when you hit the back button, the mod menu remains open. If you select `show review history` from the open menu, the URL gets all jumbled and you end up getting a 404. See (Japanese) screenshot:

[image: It looks like the show-flags is appended prior to show-reviews, hence the 404]

It looks like the show-flags is appended prior to show-reviews, hence the 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix is rolling out in next build (build rev `2016.6.17.4650` on MSE/MSO, `2016.6.17.3681` on sites).